# не показывается divder

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, divider

Доброго времени суток.
Почему-то в не отображается разделитель в LinearLayout.
Никак не могу понять с чем это связанно, заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<size android:height="1dp" />
<solid android:color="#33ffffff" /> 
</shape>
```

И код XML

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_profile"
        android:dividerPadding="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="end|middle"
        android:weightSum="160">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_weight="12"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_location" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Сиэтел, США"
                android:textColor="@color/main_light_text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bonus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonus_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="100"
                android:textColor="@color/main_light_text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="13dp"
            android:paddingLeft="27dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:paddingTop="13dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aboutTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about_profile_information"
                android:textColor="@color/main_dark_text"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datatext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="About me text..."
                android:textColor="@color/main_light_text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="81dp"
            android:layout_weight="18"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="90">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:layout_weight="18"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_vk_icon_profile" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="72"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/data"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/view_vk_profile"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_dark_text"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/data_vk_link_to_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="vk_link"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_light_text"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="81dp"
            android:layout_weight="18"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="90">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:layout_weight="18"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_icon_profile" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="72"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/send_call"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/view_vk_profile"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_dark_text"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vkPhoneData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="890123456789"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_light_text"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Атрибут `android:divider` не действует в `LinearLayout`. Я его видел лишь в `ListView`. Для разделителя достаточно использовать `View`:

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="@color/gray"/>
```

А ещё лучше использовать андроидовский стиль

```
<View
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: в вопросе про атрибут разметки `android:divider` и почему он не отображает разделитель

Comment: Потому что я такое впервые вижу, пишу `divider`-ы как `View`

Comment: @СергейГрушин Спасибо, но данное решение не особо подходит, т.к. нагромождает код(да я понимаю что моя разметка не идеально, но добавлять лишнее точно не лучший вариант). Вопрос был именно про ошибку в LinearLayout. В аналогичном коде, где не настолько большой объем элементов все прекрасно работает.
Вот и интересно есть ли ограничение и прочее

Comment: Такие вот разделители есть в `ListView`. И все прекрасно работает. Эти `View` минимально просты и поэтому нет смысла заботиться в этом случае о них. Проекты новые используют в миллионы раз мощнее `View` и все ок

Comment: @norbertf, вам предложили идеальный вариант решения вашего вопроса с неидеальной разметкой=)